# Combine a new column by selecting two columns information

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, duplicates, apply

I have a data frame with two columns information and I would like to create a new column that based on the second column and select the content that did not contain the NA value and if it is duplicated, first column will be chosen.

```
df:
200610-1    rs28619217
200610-10   NA
200610-100  rs367572771
200610-102  rs144402189
200610-105  rs375896687
200610-107  NA
200610-108  NA
200610-109  NA
200610-110  rs199838004
200610-111  rs374875201
200610-112  NA
200610-113  rs377546596
200610-114  NA
200610-115  NA
200610-116  NA
200610-117  rs67858721
200610-118  rs67858721
200610-119  rs9876735
200610-120  rs9876735

desired output:
200610-1    rs28619217  rs28619217
200610-10   NA          200610-10
200610-100  rs367572771 rs367572771
200610-102  rs144402189 rs144402189
200610-105  rs375896687 rs375896687
200610-107  NA          200610-107
200610-108  NA          200610-108
200610-109  NA          200610-109
200610-110  rs199838004 rs199838004
200610-111  rs374875201 rs374875201
200610-112  NA          200610-112
200610-113  rs377546596 rs377546596
200610-114  NA          200610-114
200610-115  NA          200610-115
200610-116  NA          200610-116
200610-117  rs67858721  rs67858721
200610-118  rs67858721  200610-118
200610-119  rs9876735   rs9876735
200610-120  rs9876735   200610-120
```

what should I do step by step? I am thinking of using apply function.

Comment: Just convert your duplicates into NAs and use any of the answers posted below. i.e. `df$V2[duplicated(df$V2)] <- NA ; df$V3 <- ifelse(is.na(df$V2), df$V1, df$V2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
df1$Col3 <- with(df1, ifelse(is.na(Col2), Col1, Col2))
df1$Col3
#[1] "rs28619217"  "200610-10"   "rs367572771" "rs144402189" "rs375896687"
#[6] "200610-107"  "200610-108"  "200610-109"  "rs199838004" "rs374875201"
#[11] "200610-112"  "rs377546596" "200610-114"  "200610-115"  "200610-116"
```

#### Update

If there are duplicates, as @Sotos mentioned in the comments, we can create a logical vector with `duplicated` as well inside the `ifelse`

```
with(df1, ifelse(is.na(Col2)|duplicated(Col2), Col1, Col2))
```

Comment: I updated my question, because I have some duplicated values in second column, would you mind help me out ? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

consider a variant of the below ...

```
df <- data.frame(colA=c(1,2,3,4),
                 colB=c("a",NA,"b","c"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$colC <- df[,2]
df[is.na(df$colC) | duplicated(df$colB),"colC"]<- df[is.na(df$colC)| duplicated(df$colB),"colA"]
```

Comment: daggummit, i found my solution that i previously posted ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079480/how-can-i-assign-the-value-from-one-of-two-posixct-columns-in-a-data-frame-to-a/37106457#37106457

Comment: I updated my question, because I have some duplicated values in second column, would you mind help me out ? thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A mutate and ifelse statement will do the work:

```
df <- read_table("200610-1    rs28619217
200610-10   NA
200610-100  rs367572771
200610-102  rs144402189
200610-105  rs375896687
200610-107  NA
200610-108  NA
200610-109  NA
200610-110  rs199838004
200610-111  rs374875201
200610-112  NA
200610-113  rs377546596
200610-114  NA
200610-115  NA
200610-116  NA", col_names = c("col1", "col2"), col_types = "cc")

df %>% 
  mutate(fill = ifelse(is.na(col2), col1, col2))

# A tibble: 15 × 3
         col1        col2        fill
        <chr>       <chr>       <chr>
1    200610-1  rs28619217  rs28619217
2   200610-10        <NA>   200610-10
3  200610-100 rs367572771 rs367572771
4  200610-102 rs144402189 rs144402189
5  200610-105 rs375896687 rs375896687
6  200610-107        <NA>  200610-107
7  200610-108        <NA>  200610-108
8  200610-109        <NA>  200610-109
9  200610-110 rs199838004 rs199838004
10 200610-111 rs374875201 rs374875201
11 200610-112        <NA>  200610-112
12 200610-113 rs377546596 rs377546596
13 200610-114        <NA>  200610-114
14 200610-115        <NA>  200610-115
15 200610-116        <NA>  200610-116
```

Comment: I updated my question, because I have some duplicated values in second column, would you mind help me out ? thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[! is.na(df[,2])]
df[,3]= paste0(df[,1], df[,2])
df = df[ unique(df[,3]), ]
df = df[,3]
```

Did it work?

```
df =
df %>% 
mutate(fill = ifelse(is.na(col2), col1, col2)) %>%
unique(df$col1)
```

Did it work?